# array to string conversion error with PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am getting an array to string conversion error when I am trying to run a PDO execute.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'root', '');
$req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `customers`');
$req->execute();
$result = $req->fetchAll();
print $result;
```

and browser show me the error "Notice: Array to string conversion" and only print "Array"

Comment: Use [`print_r`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r) or [`var_dump`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php). [`print`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) only works with simple structures like strings and numbers.

Comment: use print_r($result);

Comment: You can get first element `print $result[0];`

Answer (score -1):

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'root', '');
$req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `customers`');
$req->execute();
$result = $req->fetchAll();

print_r($result); 
var_dump($result);

foreach($result as $key => $value){
    $id = $value['id'];

}
```